# Is there a workaround to get proper font support in SVG loaded in an <img> tag in Chrome + Safari?

Tags: html, google-chrome, svg, webkit, cross-browser

I'm using a data URI with my SVG markup and sticking it in the `src` attribute of an `<img>` tag.  Works fine in FireFox, but in Chrome/Safari I lose the font support.

See here:  http://jsfiddle.net/3vhR7/

Is there a workaround for this such that I can still use `<img>` instead of `<embed>` or `<object>`?

EDIT: I submitted this to [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com) and they [confirmed it as a bug](http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-img)

Comment: Include the glyphs in the svg

Comment: Unfortunately that's not an option for me.  Anything else?

Comment: What do you mean with 'lose the font support'? The two svg's in your fiddle both look the same to me (in Chrome).

Comment: Not for me (latest version of chrome on OS X Snow Leopard.  Also, here's a screen shot from my iPhone (latest version of iOS), so I guess it's not just a Chrome issue after all: http://d.pr/i/xuDe

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use an object tag?  It's easy and super fun.

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="chart.svg">
    <img src="fallback.png" alt="No SVG Support"/>     
</object>
```

YAY! (the Monty Python version)

Comment: Appreciate the response. I can't remember why right now, but at the time there was a distinct benefit I came across to using <img> instead of <object>. Maybe it was CSS related, can't remember. Anyhow, I ended up not needing to display SVG files after all!