# SVG fill and link not working

Tags: css, object, svg, hyperlink, fill

Here's my html:

```
<a href="#"> <object type ="image/svg+xml" class="dribbble" 
data="img/dribbble.svg"></object></a>
```

And here's the CSS:

```
.dribbble{
fill: #ffffff;
width: 40px;
height: 40px;}
```

I saved the svg with a fill in Illustrator, so I went into the svg code and deleted that fill. However, the white fill I have in the CSS isn't showing up at all, and the icon itself is showing up as black. It's also supposed to be a link, and is currently unclickable

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906148/how-to-apply-a-style-to-an-embedded-svg and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11374059/make-an-html-svg-object-also-a-clickable-link.