# Adding a hyperlink to object data image

Tags: html, css, svg

I am having problems with adding a hyperlink to my image. It is a SVG image which is an object data. I seem to have trouble with getting the hyperlink to work. Am i doing it wrong?

```
<div id="logo" class="grid_4">

<object data="img/flogo.svg" type="image/svg+xml" class="logo">
<!--[if lte IE 8 ]-->
<img src="img/flogo.gif" alt="F-Sharp Media Logo">
<!--![endif]-->
</object>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

From [Here](https://teamtreehouse.com/forum/how-do-you-make-a-svg-clickable) and [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11374059/make-an-html-svg-object-also-a-clickable-link)..

**CSS:**

```
a.svg {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block; 
}
a.svg:after {
  content: ""; 
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left:0;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#" class="svg">
    <object data="img/flogo.svg" type="image/svg+xml" class="logo">
        <!--[if lte IE 8 ]-->
        <img src="img/flogo.gif" alt="F-Sharp Media Logo">
        <!--![endif]-->
    </object>
</a>
```