# Click behavior changes on SVG when changing between<img> and <object>

Tags: html, css, svg, graphics, click

I have 4 SVG buttons as part of a main menu on my personal webpage.

[image]

/----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------/

When one is clicked, all 4 buttons retract to the corners and the respective section is revealed (i.e. AboutMe button --> AboutMe section).
[image]

**Originally I had the SVG objects embedded in an img tag like so:**

```
<img class = "button active" id = "person-icon" src = "resources/main-page-icons/person-icon.svg"/>
```

I did it like this because I read that when there is no need to animate an SVG it isn't necessary to embed it in an object/embed tag. However, I decided today that I wanted to create a hover effect for the SVG element. I had to change the img tag to an object to allow for styling/animating

```
<object class = "button active" id = "person-icon" data = "resources/main-page-icons/person-icon.svg" type = "image/svg+xml"></object>
```

The hover effect works as expected, **BUT now I can't click it**. Inspecting the element reveals that I'm **clicking on the SVG itself** and **not the object it's embedded in**. Wrapping it in a div did not solve the problem either.

Question:
Is there a way I can animate the SVG element while handling click events on the object element it's embedded in?

In case someone asks "Why not handle the click event within the SVG element?"
I don't think it's possible or would make sense for an SVG element's behavior to influence other elements which is why I handled the click events **OUTSIDE** of the SVG element (i.e. click 1 button --> other buttons expand, content faded in = bad). Maybe you can, but I didn't think it made sense and it wasn't necessary initially.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Images are not interactive by design. If you have a mental model of an image that their capabilities are on a par with a raster you won't go far wrong.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're saying/suggesting. I understand that images are not interactive, that's why I changed to an object tag.

Comment: If you don't send the click events to the object you can't trigger the animation can you? It's a bit hard to be definitive as you've not provided the image source code or any details of how the animation works.

Comment: Because this case obviously had to do with the changing of the element type I figured it was more of a fundamental JQuery/HTML problem and didn't require specific code. I was able to find the answer on my own after a while. Thanks for the input nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25916403/how-to-bind-click-event-to-object-tag/25916723) after some time Googling:

> This kind of tag  needs some content to show up on the page.
>
> Your tag:
>
> `<object data="images/logo.svg" type="image/svg+xml" class="icon-logo"></object>`
>
> is not having any inner HTML-Content, so you won't be able to click it.

This has to do with an object requiring some sort of innerHTML in order to be recognized by the DOM. If I added some text like `<object>Zoot!</object>` then I could click it. Additionally, the SVG DOM differs fundamentally than the HTML DOM and lacks innerHTML. More on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294553/jquery-selector-svg-incompatible).

The work around was to use an image tag and surround it in a div that I can animate/style on. This works for the most part, but in my case the div is a circle (border-radius: 50%) and when translated across the screen skews the shape. Looks goofy when a background/border is applied and the skewing is visible. That's for another post though!

Answer (score 1):

This is because, for security reasons, events that occur on framed documents won't bubble to the main document.
`<object>` element's content is a framed document and do suffer from this restrictions too.

To workaround this, you have to attach the event onto the element's `contentWindow`, or any element inside its `contentDocument`.

But the document will not be accessible for cross-domain resources loaded into the element.

So you may try some kind of a hack like [proposed here by @PaulDrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23231136/3702797) which listens for the blur event and check what is the actual `activeElement` of the main `document`.

But there may be some false-positives if the user set the focus on the element using <kbd>Tab</kbd> navigation.

```js
function attachClickEvent(obj, callback) {
  // no cross-domain restrictions
  if (obj.contentWindow) {
    obj.contentWindow.addEventListener('click', function() {
      callback();
    });
  } else {
    // hacky workaround
    window.addEventListener('blur', function() {
      // activeElement may not have been updated yet
      requestAnimationFrame(function() {
        // check that our element is the active one
        if (document.activeElement === obj) {
          callback();
          // so we can detect it multiple times
          obj.blur()
        }
      });
    });
    // we need to set the focus on the document
    var inp = document.createElement('input');
    inp.style.position = 'absolute';
    inp.style.opacity = 0;
    document.body.appendChild(inp);
    inp.focus();
    document.body.removeChild(inp);
  }

};

// call it when the element has loaded
crossDomain.onload = function() {
  attachClickEvent(this, function() {
    snippet.log('clicked on the doc')
  })
};
// for some UA, the load event may already have fired, so reload it ;-)
crossDomain.data = crossDomain.data;
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>

<object width="200px" id="crossDomain" data="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fd/Ghostscript_Tiger.svg"></object>
```