# HTML <div> with SVG onclick issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, svg, z-index

I have a parent div with child object tag that contains my svg.

I'm trying to capture the clicks on my image but it doesn't work.

In the sample code snippet, the alert is shown only when one click's outside the displayed svg.

HTML:

```
<div class="calendarWidget" onclick="alert('test');">
    <span>
        <object  onclick="alert('test1');" data="https://www.multiservicetolls.com/wp-content/uploads/revslider/assets/svg/busy-icons-svg/folder-private.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
    </span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.calendarWidget {
  position: fixed;
  max-width: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
  background-color:green;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/50cbetd2/6/)

Due to my requirement, I can't write the script code within the svg.

Comment: You need to capture only clicks on svg?

Comment: yes, when use clicks on the svg image i need to fetch data using ajax and display in a bootstrap modal.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25916403/how-to-bind-click-event-to-object-tag

Comment: Try the onclick event on the wrapping `<span>`. The `<object>` element can't be clicked.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using `<object>`? Clicks on object elements are passed through to the child to handle.  Hence your problem.  Why not just use an `<img>` element instead?

Comment: The reason I'm using an object instead of an <img> tag is because the js within the svg doesn't execute in the <img> tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest route is to keep the handler on the div, and set the browser to ignore mouse events on the svg with the css `pointer-events: none;`. Run the snippet below to see it work (I moved the svg to the top left for the sake of this demo).

```css
.calendarWidget {
  position: fixed;
  max-width: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  background-color:green;
  z-index: 1;
}
.ignoreMouse{
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="calendarWidget" onclick="alert('test');">
  <span>
    <object class="ignoreMouse" data="https://www.multiservicetolls.com/wp-content/uploads/revslider/assets/svg/busy-icons-svg/folder-private.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
   </span>
</div>
```