# 'onclick' does not work on an object-element with an svg-image

Tags: javascript, html

When I use the `onclick` attribute of an `object`-element in an html document, it does not respond to clicks.

In my document I have an svg image and store that in an `object`-element, since there is some animation in the image that would get lost by just using an `img`-tag.

In the simplified example below, the `onmouseover` works on both objects, but the `onclick` just works on the `object` without the svg-image.

```js
document.getElementById('test1').onmouseover = hover;
document.getElementById('test1').onclick = click;
document.getElementById('test2').onmouseover = hover;
document.getElementById('test2').onclick = click;

function hover() { alert('Hovered');};
function click() { alert('Clicked');};
```

```html
<object id='test1' data="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/01/SVG_Circle.svg" height="50px"></object>

<object id='test2' height="50px" border="1px solid black">some object</object>
```

Is there something I am doing wrong here? Or is there an alternative that does work?

The answers given for [this (and related questions)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25916403/how-to-bind-click-event-to-object-tag) advise to use `pointer-events: none` on the svg-image and wrap it in a div and apply the listeners to that div. But I need the svg-image to respond to `mouse events`, and therefore cannot set `pointier-events: none`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After a bit of research, I found that your main issue is:

> The `<object>` tag **can not be clicked.** (*)

*(*)Unless the `<object>` tag is empty, it's behavior will be the same as an `<iframe>` tag, which is strictly limited by CORS policy and the browser will block any attempt to modify the source.*

### Why?

The [CORS security policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) is a mechanism that uses additional [HTTP headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers) to tell (or give permission) to a browser to use and manipulate the external domain contents.

This is a security policy because imagine this:

*Someone has a malicious website called `stackoverflow.co`.  And this malicious person decides to load trough an iframe the website `stackoverflow.com` and manipulate its content to trick users into a fake login page and when users inputs his private credentials he's not loggin into the official site, so his credentials will be stolen by the malicious site.*

Well, CORS is the hero here. Thanks to this security policy, the remote servers can send an additional header that is seen like this: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` and the browser determines that if any of this contents are loaded trough an `<iframe>` or `<object>` tag, any attempt to modify the contents of this should be blocked.

Since in 2019 this is now a [standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) in the web, most browsers detect this CORS header and prevents this kind of exploit.

### So, what should you do?

Well, if your issue is that you need to load the svg, the quickest solution is to load it trough an `<img>` tag.

Otherwise, there is no way you'll be able to inject, use, handle or whatever in an `<object>` nor `<iframe>` tag with the CORS header included. Except for the `onload`.

**Aditional sources:**

The user who answered a similar question time ago can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25916723/5568741).

Comment: It is a duplicate, and for the reason `<object>` can't have `click` event. Whether one use jQuery or plain javascript doesn't matter.

Comment: Furthermore, don't add such noise as telling why a question is not a dupe, just focus on answering.

Answer (score 3):

The following code should do the trick:

```html
<div id='test1'>
    <object style="pointer-events: none;" height="50px" data="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/01/SVG_Circle.svg"></object>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment. If you look at my code, you can see that the object element is wrapped in a div element thus everything inside it will react to `pointer-events`. My guess is that you have not tried my code before downvoting. I hope you will try it, so you will become wiser and make stackoverflow a better place.Thanks!

Comment: But the svg-image still will not react to mouse events anymore, not even to hover-events!

Comment: You can test the code here: https://jsfiddle.net/tvrxekbf/

Comment: I know, that your solution works for this example. But the svg image i am using, also uses javascript and css, and thereby react to mouse-events. This is not possible anymore, if pointer-events are set to none.