# Click on SVG image (JS)

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have some SVG images on my html page. I want get id of each image by click on it.
HTML:

```
<div class = "svgLoading"><object data="images/91.svg" type="image/svg+xml" id = "47"></object></div>
<div class = "svgPoints"><object data="images/30.svg" type="image/svg+xml" id = "48"></object></div>
```

I'm trying to get them like this:

```
document.body.onclick = function(event) {
var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
alert(target.tagName); }
```

Its working fine for other elements, for example: img, div without object.
But clicking on the svg is ignored. Why is this happening and how to properly handle clicks on svg?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The  tag can not be clicked but you can make a workaround and set the click action to parent. ( [Take a look at this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56082774/onclick-does-not-work-on-an-object-element-with-an-svg-image) )

Set the object pointer-events to [none](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events#Syntax), in order to make the element to be never the target of pointer events:

> The element is never the target of pointer events; however, pointer events may target its descendant elements if those descendants have pointer-events set to some other value. In these circumstances, pointer events will trigger event listeners on this parent element

```js
$("#svg_47").click(function(target) {
  var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
  console.log("object id: " + target.firstElementChild.id)
  alert(target.tagName);
});
```

```css
object {
  width: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="svgLoading" id="svg_47">
  <object data="https://css-tricks.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/kiwi.svg" type="image/svg+xml" id="47"></object>
</div>

<div class="svgPoints" id="svg_87">
  <object data="https://svgsilh.com/svg/1801287.svg" type="image/svg+xml" id="48"></object>
</div>
```

Comment: Solver by `pointer-events: none;` simply, many thanks.