# Can't trigger onclick event on a <object> html element

Tags: html, object, events

I write this simple htlm file :

```
<svg onclick="alert('Click svg!')" style="height: 200px; width: 200px; background-color: green"></svg>
<div onclick="alert('Click div!')" style="height: 200px; width: 200px; background-color: red"></div>
<object onclick="alert('Click object!')" data="./bank.svg" type="image/svg+xml" style="height: 4308.75px; width: 7660px;"></object>
```

When I click on the svg, I trigger the onclick event and get the alert 'Click svg!'.

When I click on the div, I trigger the onclick event and get the alert 'Click div!'.

When I click on the object, I trigger nothing.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Object tags don't really support click events (see for example [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25916403/how-to-bind-click-event-to-object-tag)) I couldn't find a source for the comment on which elements don't support clicks but nevertheless: It's not 1990 anymore, there is no reason to still be using `<object>` tag for SVGs. Nowadays you can just render the SVG inline.

If you want to add click events, use a `<button type="button">` to bind to the buttons click events and handle these. Don't be scared off by how a button looks by default, you can style it any way you want. Don't put click events on divs or other elements, this is not accessible.

Adding click events to divs/ spans / (anything else than a button, really) is not really good practice and should best be avoided altogether.

```
<button type="button" onclick="alert('clicked')">
  <svg> ... </svg>
</button>
```

Comment: Ok thanks, I will head toward inline SVG then