# Hoverable and Clickable svg

Tags: object, svg, hyperlink, hover

I am trying to create a set of icons in svg that have some hover effects in them. I then have each of these icons wrapped in an `<a>` but when the page is loaded, the icons are not clickable, but do show their hover effects.

I've tried numerous fixes such as appending an absolutely positioned :before with height and width and transparent background, which creates a clickable area but the icon itself then loses the interactivity. I've also tried using the svg in `<img>` which again allows it to be clicked but loses the interactivity of it.

This is the code set up I am using:

```
<a href="/batteries" class="svg-link">
    <object type="image/svg+xml" class="svg-icon" data="{{ asset('img/icons/servicing/batteries-car-active.svg') }}">
    </object>
</a>
```

The hover effects are in the svg file itself.

Comment: Hey i think this is answered here already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11374059/make-an-html-svg-object-also-a-clickable-link

Comment: The easiest way would be to have the SVG handle the click. At the moment you want the container to handle some interaction and the contents to handle some, that's not really going to fly very easily.

Comment: Persijn I have looked a that answer before and unfortunately the use of '<img>' means that I lose the hover effects in the svg.

@RobertLongson How would I go about structuring it work better?

Comment: Move the link into the SVG. I.e. use an SVG  `<a>` element rather than an html  `<a>` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has fixed the issue:

```
<a xlink:href="/servicing/{{ $masterTemplateType }}/batteries">
</a>
```

The `<a>` being wrapped around the body of the svg, after the `<style>` and before the closing `</svg>`