# make an html svg object also a clickable link (on iphone)

Tags: html, css, iphone, svg

This question is the same as [make an html svg object also a clickable link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11374059/4825796), but the answers given do not seem to work on an iPhone ios 9.3 (safari and chrome browsers).  Im re-asking this question in hopes that their are new methods to resolve the problem or an adaptation to the answers to work with an iPhone.

Also, using a tag other than the `<object>` tag is not possible in my situation.

CSS

```
.tab-svg-link {
    display: block;
    z-index: 1;/*added this to test if it fixes the problem*/

    overflow: hidden;
    float: left !important;
    width: 325px;
    height: 280px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.tab-svg-object{
   z-index: -1;/*added this to test if it fixes the problem*/
   pointer-events: none;
}

/*update 3 -- added containing divs for code completion */

.index-container {
     padding: 15px 20px;
}

.layout-content {
     margin-top: 75px;
}
```

HTML

```
<body>
    <div class="layout-content container"> <!--container bootstrap class-->
        <div class="index-container">
            <div class="tab-content"> <!--tab-content bootstrap class-->
                <div class="tab-pane"> <!--tab-pane bootstrap class-->
                    <a href="link.php" class="tab-svg-link"> 
                        <object type="image/svg+xml" style="visibility:visible !important" id='svg-object-1' class="tab-svg-object"
                            data="dir/my.svg">Your browser does not
                            support SVGs
                        </object>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

The code above creates this:

[image]

If I click the orange area (this is the achor) it works, but if I click on top of the SVG (`<object>`) it doesnt.  The code above works on my windows computer, mac, and android phone on firefox, chrome, and internet explorer.

---

Update:

My anchor is inside a Bootstrap `tab-content` class object.  I have also updated my html code to display bootstrap parent objects of my anchor.

Update 2:

I have trying removing Bootstrap from my project, in case of any unknown interference or declaration, and the problem still remained.

Update 3 :

Updated image and added all parent objects with their css.

Answer (score 3):

The image you shared suggests that your styles are getting over-ridden because I can somehow see it's coming out of a container from the bottom despite that you've set overflow hidden...
Try adding clearfix to your link (`<a>` tag)

```
.tab-svg-link:after {
  content:"";
  display:table;
  clear:both;
}
```

```css
.tab-svg-link {
  display: block;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
.tab-svg-link:after {
  content:"";
  display:table;
  clear:both;
}
.tab-svg-object {
  pointer-events: none;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="link.php" class="tab-svg-link">
  <object type="image/svg+xml" style="visibility:visible !important" id='svg-object-1' class="tab-svg-object" data="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/02/SVG_logo.svg">Your browser does not support SVGs
  </object>
</a>
```

If that doesn't help consider sharing the url to your site... You can also hook your iPhone to your Mac (via USB) and inspect the elements to check out what's wrong...

---

### Update - Inspecting pages on iPhone with Safari on Mac

1. On your iPhone, go to "Settings > Safari > Advanced" and turn on "Web Inspector".
2. Attach your iPhone to your Mac via USB cable.
3. Open `Safari` open `Develop` in menu and go to your device and click on webpage (it will show webpages open on your device) you'd like to inspect.
4. Web Inspector works ;-)

Comment: Im unable to pass a link to the site because it is not yet live.  The part of the image that was overlapping in the bottom was because i added a border to that square when creating the image (ive updated the image).  I altered my code to what you suggested and it still does work.  I currently program on my windows computer, but do you have link on how to inspect the elements using my mac and iphone, as suggested in your last statement.

Comment: Added `Inspecting pages on iPhone with Safari on mac` section... Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 1):

For me it is working just fine, even on iOS!

However, a little JS/jQuery should do the trick in case its not working on some systems:

```
$('a').on('touchend, click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var url = $(this).attr('href');
  window.location = url;
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
$('a').on('touchend, click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var url = $(this).attr('href');
  window.location = url;
});
```

```css
.tab-svg-link {
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
  /*added this to test if it fixes the problem*/
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 325px;
  height: 280px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
.tab-svg-object {
  z-index: -1;
  /*added this to test if it fixes the problem*/
  pointer-events: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="link.php" class="tab-svg-link">
  <object type="image/svg+xml" style="visibility:visible !important" id='svg-object-1' class="tab-svg-object" data="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/02/SVG_logo.svg">Your browser does not support SVGs
  </object>
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I still get the same results even when I added your javascript code.  To clarify, the code  I have works on ios on my macbook but not on my iphone 6.

Comment: My anchor is inside a bootstrap `tab-content` class object, if it makes any difference.  I dont believe this would have any effect on the anchor, but thats the only difference between yours working and mine not. - @cocoseis

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `onclick=""` to the `object` element. I have had to add that to `label` elements to make them tappable on ios.

```
<object onclick="" type="image/svg+xml" style="visibility:visible !important" id='svg-object-1' class="tab-svg-object" data="dir/my.svg">
    Your browser does not support SVGs
</object>
```

Comment: Added what you said and still not working.  Ill keep this in mind for the future do, thanks.