# Anchor href attribute in SVG not working on mobile browsers

Tags: html, css, svg

I have an encapsulated svg with a href a attribute link inside. Unfortunately the link does not work on most mobile browsers (Safari, Firefox, ect.) I tested on iPhone, iPad, LG phone, Samsung Galaxy Tablet.

This is my code inside the HTML and inside the outer SVG:

```
<svg width="400px" height="400px" font-size="55px" font-family="Open Sans" font-weight="bold">
<!--LINK EMBEDDED IN SVG-->
  <a href="https://www.nzz.ch" target="_blank" class="svg-link">
    <text x="50%" y="50%" text-anchor="middle" fill="white">CLICKME</text>
  </a>
</svg>
```

Full code is:

```html
<html>
<body>
  <div style="font-family:Open Sans;font-size:15px;padding:30px;position:absolute;">
    Test for text clickable on mobile
  </div>
  <svg width="600px" height="600px" fill-opacity="0.8">
    <circle r="200" cx="300" cy="300" style="fill:#11db4d;">
    </circle>
    <g transform="translate(100,100)">
    <svg width="400px" height="400px" font-size="55px" font-family="Open Sans" font-weight="bold">
      <!--LINK EMBEDDED IN SVG-->
      <a href="https://www.nzz.ch" target="_blank">
        <text x="50%" y="50%" text-anchor="middle" fill="white">CLICKME</text>
      </a>
    </svg>
  </g>
  </svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Or here on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sqhy8p15/2/ I also tried to change the z-index and padding as suggested in the answers here [make an html svg object also a clickable link (on iphone)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38107006/make-an-html-svg-object-also-a-clickable-link-on-iphone#38223317) but it did not work (https://jsfiddle.net/yau5wzrf/2/).

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Thanks for editing!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of Attribute `href` use `xlink:href`
Also make sure that the `xlink` namespace is delcared on your SVG element.

See: [https://alligator.io/svg/hyperlinks-svg/](https://web.archive.org/web/20211014123403/https://alligator.io/svg/hyperlinks-svg/)