# How to convert image map coords to SVG path format?

Tags: image, svg, photoshop

I've extracted selected area coords from images on Photoshop and want to convert 'em to plain SVG path format. I can't find any proper method how to do this, please help.

Comment: What sort of image is it?  Does your shape have just straight lines, or does it have curves as well?  Please expand your question with more information, so we can offer appropriate advice.

Comment: Hi Paul, it's a plain JPG image and shape have straight lines and curves. For example I want to convert this extracted coords:
`<map name="imageMap">
<area shape="poly" coords="681,228,681,340,458,340,446,427,686,528,704,610,704,630,696,668,664,728,543,804,507,810,449,814,429,814,374,806,317,790,296,780,302,755,316,703,321,682,325,681,376,698,552,664,566,619,562,593,488,534,446,528,388,526,365,526,326,530,326,529,328,513,334,464,356,294,362,246,364,229,388,228,450,228" href="***Work Path***.html" alt="Work Path" title="Work Path"/>
</map>`

Answer (score 2):

You can generally just transfer your image map list of coordinates to the `points` attribute of an SVG `<polygon>` element.

My answer in the following question has examples of what that looks like.

[How to make a responsive and interactive Image map using SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47198415/how-to-make-a-responsive-and-interactive-image-map-using-svg)

Comment: True for Polygon but not `rect` which is x1,y1,x2,y2 whereas SVG just uses a series of x,y coords