# svg links not working when inserted in visual composer toggle tag

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

[Here is the link to the page.](https://alexanderlabs.co.ke/salesmatetest/identity-management/)

---

Here is  the code used to implement

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <p class="main-block-title">IDENTITY MANAGEMENT</p>
    &nbsp;    
    <img class="padding-0-20" src="https://salesmate.technobraingroup.com/wp-content/themes/salesmateV1/images/idm_svg_circle edited.svg" />    
</div>
```

Comment: <div class="col-md-6">
<p class="main-block-title">IDENTITY MANAGEMENT</p>
<img class="padding-0-20" src="https://salesmate.technobraingroup.com/wp-content/themes/salesmateV1/images/idm_svg_circle edited.svg" />
</div>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that when you are using `img` tag with SVG files, the links are not working.

The solution are:

1. Embed the SVG code as is

https://codepen.io/moshfeu/pen/Ryyrqy

2. Use an `object` tag instead of `img`:

```css
object {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<object data="//salesmate.technobraingroup.com/wp-content/themes/salesmateV1/images/idm_svg_circle edited.svg" />
```

Like described in the question [make an html svg object also a clickable link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11374059/863110)

Comment: I don't see you did so.. Is your site up to date?

Comment: anyone facing this problem our guru @mosh feu will post a solution to this soon. he is really of much help.

Comment: *I haven't tested this*; but I embed SVG straight into HTML, no wrapper tag and with the *right namespaces* you should be able to use HTML5

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What `wrapper` tag and `namespaces` are you talking about? Can you show me your code?