# How to make my object redirect the whole page not just itself

Tags: javascript, object, dom

I have an SVG in my  tag. When I click on it, I want to redirect the page.

```
<object class="SVGClass centered" data="/Data/Blue_Force.svg" type="image/svg+xml" id="BF1SVG"style="margin:20px"></object>
<script>
var SVG1 = document.getElementById("BF1SVG");
var SVGElements1;
var SVGLoaded1 = false;
    if(!SVGLoaded){
        SVG1.addEventListener('load',function(){ 
            SVGLoaded1 = true;
            SVGElements1 = SVG1.contentDocument;

      SVGElements1.getElementById("svgCC").setAttributeNS(null, "onclick", "window.location.href='http://686amppi5.campus.nist.gov/cryoConceptsStateViewer.html'");
});
</script>
```

svgCC is the id of the external SVG. When i click on it, the object itself becomes the new page, like an embedded window, rather than redirecting the browser.

I've also tried:

```
document.getElementById("BF1SVG").setAttribute("onclick", "window.location.href='http://686amppi5.campus.nist.gov/cryoConceptsStateViewer.html'");
```

but that just does nothing. my svg is not clickable.

Answer (score 1):

You should not set the onclick attrbute that way... try this instead.

```
document.getElementById("BF1SVG").addEventListener(
    'click', 
    () => window.location.assign('http://686amppi5.campus.nist.gov/cryoConceptsStateViewer.html');
);
```

Comment: This does not make my object clickable. Same result as my first fix.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem is the object tags aren't clickable. The easiest way around it seems to be wrapping the object in a div or some other regular tag and then adding `object { pointer-events: none; }` to your stylesheet.

See these threads for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17133804/11886299 and [Add onclick event to newly added element in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3316207/add-onclick-event-to-newly-added-element-in-javascript)

```js
var SVG1 = document.getElementById("BF1SVG");
var SVGElements1;
var SVGLoaded1 = false;
    if(!SVGLoaded1){
        SVG1.addEventListener('load',function(){ 
            SVGLoaded1 = true;
            SVGElements1 = SVG1.contentDocument;
            this.parentElement.addEventListener(
              "click",
              function(){
                window.location.href="http://686amppi5.campus.nist.gov/cryoConceptsStateViewer.html"

            });
});
}
```

```css
object { pointer-events: none; }
```

```html
<div>
<object class="SVGClass centered" data="https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/android.svg" type="image/svg+xml" id="BF1SVG"style="margin:20px"></object>

</div>
```