# .SVG file object clickable under anchor tag

Tags: css

I have one scenario, where I need to clickable .svg file object which is under anchor tag and  div.

I have solution to add `display:inline-block` to the div(`.svg-wrapper`) or anchor tag. However, I need `Display:contents` for anchor tag as well as on div due to some CSS functionality.

```css
.component-content{
      display: flex;
      overflow: hidden;
}
a{
      display: contents;
}
.svg-wrapper{
  display: contents;
}
.svg-container{
    height: auto;
    align-self: start;
    padding: 0 19px 0 0;
    max-width: 50%;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="component-content">
<a href="http://google">
<div class="svg-wrapper">
<object class="svg-container" type="image/svg+xml"  data="https://beta.designforventures.co/Free-Animated-SVG-Icons/warehouse/youtube-icon-dark-grey.svg">
<img  src="https://beta.designforventures.co/Free-Animated-SVG-Icons/warehouse/youtube-icon-dark-grey.svg">
</object>
</div>
</a> 
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [make an html svg object also a clickable link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11374059/make-an-html-svg-object-also-a-clickable-link)

Comment: Thank you Mike for commenting. However, mentioned link is not working with my html.

Comment: Removing display:contents from the _a_ should be sufficient, you said you need to keep it in svg-wrapper and it can stay there, remove it from _a_ and it will work

Comment: I need display:contents for both(anchor as well as on div) , I have updated my question for the better understanding.

Comment: Could anyone assist me on this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the object element with another div. I couldn't find any other solution.
Check it out: https://jsfiddle.net/4qdLx5n9/2/

```
<div class="component-content">
  <a href="http://google">
    <div class="svg-wrapper">
      <div>
        <object class="svg-container" type="image/svg+xml" data="https://beta.designforventures.co/Free-Animated-SVG-Icons/warehouse/youtube-icon-dark-grey.svg">
          <img src="https://beta.designforventures.co/Free-Animated-SVG-Icons/warehouse/youtube-icon-dark-grey.svg">
        </object>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

@edit There's one more solution to your problem, adding an `::after` with `position: absolute` to the anchor element and `position:relative` to component-content works as well:
https://jsfiddle.net/j7yx648w/3/

```
.component-content {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

a {
  display: contents;
}

a:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.svg-wrapper {
  display: contents;
}

.svg-container {
  height: auto;
  align-self: start;
  padding: 0 19px 0 0;
  max-width: 50%;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Mike for answering, However, it wont solve my issue as I will not add any extra div.

Comment: @Ashu I've updated the answer with an additional solution, try it

Comment: Thanks Mike , It is working, Only concerns , it is working without adding position: relative at component-content class. Is it fine ?

Comment: It depends on what's the structure of your html, check the fiddle i've attached and remove the position: relative, it will make the whole container clickable